# Botão carregar + Dados do Banco de Dados MYSQL substituindo "Select * From tabela limit 18"

Tags: mysql

Estou querendo configurar um botão para que sempre quando eu aperta no botão CARREGAR + o limit 18 acrescente sempre +18.

EXEMPLO:
$sql = "SELECT * FROM portfolio ORDER BY id DESC limit 18";

**BOTÃO CLICKADO**

$sql = "SELECT * FROM portfolio ORDER BY id DESC limit 36";

**BOTÃO CLICKADO**

$sql = "SELECT * FROM portfolio ORDER BY id DESC limit 54";

Eu coloquei esse limit para arrumar o layout e aparecer apenas 18 blocos no meu site e ir carregando sempre +18 ao aperta no botão.

CODIGO:

```
<div class="grid">

      <?php
$servidor = 'localhost';
$banco      = 'apixel_galeria';
$usuario  = 'root';
$senha    = '';
$link     = @mysql_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha);
$db          = mysql_select_db($banco,$link);
if(!$link)
{
    echo "erro ao conectar ao banco de dados!";exit();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM portfolio ORDER BY id DESC limit 18";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

while($sql = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$id = $sql["id"];
$nome = $sql["nome"];
$tipo = $sql["tipo"];
$desc = $sql["desc"];
$menu = $sql["menu"];
$imageM = $sql["imageM"];
$imageF = $sql["imageF"];
    ?>
          <div class="element-item <?php echo "$menu";?>" data-category="transition">
       <a href="#portfolioModal54" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                                <img src="<?php echo "$imageM"?>" alt="project 2">
             <div class="mask">    <div class="conteudo_mask" style="
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    position: relative;
    /* float: left; */
    ">                   <h1><?php echo "$nome"?></h1>                   <div id="lin" style="
    width: 200px;
"></div>                   <h2><?php echo "$tipo"?></h2>                                                    </div><h3 style="
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    position: relative;
">VEJA <br><img src="images/mais.png" alt="mais" style="width: 20px;height: 19px;margin-bottom: -1px;margin-top: 3px;"></h3></div>
                                </a>
  </div>

        <?php
}
?>
</div>
        <!-- BOTÃO CARREGAR MAIS-->
       <div id="rend-more">
            <button class="button bt1" style="width: 262px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid rgb(84, 128, 128); position: relative; top: 30%; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); cursor: pointer;  background-color: white;">
                <h2 style="text-align: center;color:#4d8984;font-family: 'Gotham-Thin';float: left;font-size: 25px;padding-left: 30px;padding-top: 5px;">CARREGAR</h2>
                <h3 style="padding-left: 5px;float: left;font-size: 25px;color:#4d8984;font-family: 'gotham-bold';padding-top: 5px;">+</h3></button>
        </div>
```

Comment: O que você quer se chama PAGINAÇÃO. Veja [**este tutorial**](https://daltonmenezes.wordpress.com/2010/06/17/paginacao-de-resultados-com-php-e-mysql-aprenda-definitivamente-no-passo-a-passo/) e veja se te ajuda.

Comment: Não faz sentido isso, você estará pegando todos os valores já obtidos anteriormente a cada clique. Mantenha o limite e mude o WHERE para > que o último ID pego no clique anterior. Claro que aí vai ter que mudar a lógica da página para carregar dinamicamente, ou fazer paginado.

Comment: então amigo, é dinamicamente, ao aperta ele ja carrega em baixo as outras.

Comment: Bacco não entendi como vou fazer isso rs, poderia me explicar?

Comment: Pois não vejo um where no meu codigo.

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde amigo ,

EDIT --

Pelo seu comentaria acima,você quer que os dados sejam carregados dinamicamente , certo ? 
Então voce vai precisar sober sobre um pouco de ajax.

Edit --

Abaixo , segue um pequeno exemplo , lembrando que nao validei tudo e nem formatei o html , é um exemplo simples .

Na pagina pegaPortifolio.php , você fará o o select no banco  , trazendo os resultados dos dados  , com um limit definido por você.

pagina : pegaPortifolio.php

```
    <?php

function fn_conexao(){

    $dbuser = "admin";
    $dbpass = "1234";

    try {

        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=seu_banco',  $dbuser, $dbpass);
        $pdo -> setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
        $pdo->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");//corrige os acentos na hora de gravar no BD
    } catch(Exception $e) {

        echo 'Erro na conexao: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    return $pdo;
}

function dados($pdo){

    try {   

            if(!isset($_GET['id']) or $_GET['id'] == null){

                $id = 0; //se o GET nao for enviado o for enviado como nullo , a variável ID pega o valor de 0

            }else {

                $id = $_GET['id']; //pega o valor passado via GET
            }

            $arr = array();

          //aqui , coloquei o limit como 2 para ficar mais facil os testes
            $sql = "SELECT * from portifolio where id > $id limit 2";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            $linha = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if($stmt->rowCount() >= 1){

                return $linha; //retorna o resultado da query

            }else {

                return 0;

            }
        } catch(Exception $e) {

            print 'Erro ao inserir os dados no banco: ' . $e->getMessage();
            $conexao = desconecta($conexao);

        }
}

$conexao = fn_conexao();
$dados = dados($conexao);

$dados = json_encode($dados); //converte o resultado para json

print $dados; //imprime os dados na tela
?>
```

Na sua pagina que exibira o protifolio , você ira fazer uma requisição para pegar os dados retornados em json.

portifolio.php

```
    <script>

var corpo = ""; //define a variavel corpo como global

function pegaDados()
{
    var id = document.getElementById("ultimo_id").value; //pega o valor do campo "ultimo_id"

    jQuery.ajax
        ({

            url: "json.php?id="+id,
            dataType: "json", //Tipo de Retorno
            success:
            function(data) {

                var pt1 = "";
                var i = 1;
                var ultimo_id = 0;

                  var size = 0, key;
                  for (key in data) {
                        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++; //cod para contar o tamanho do array multidimensional

                    }//size , variavel com o tamamho do array

                 for(i = 0; i < size; i++){ //monta o html para exibir os dados

                     pt1 += '<div id="nome">Nome: '+data[i].nome+'</div> <div id="foto">Foto: '+data[i].img+'</div>';
                     ultimo_id = data[i].id;
                  }

                  monta_html(pt1);
                 document.getElementById("ultimo_id").value = ultimo_id; //atribui o valor do ultimo id para o campo "ultimo_id"                    

            }
        });

}


function monta_html(dados){

  corpo += dados; //pega os dados da funcao pegaDados , a junta aos dados que ja tem armazenado, assim ,sempre que clicar no botao 
                  //CARREGA +  , ele manterá os dados que foram pesquisados antes.
                  //Assim ,é feita uma consulta pequena ,nao sendo necessarios pesquisar os dados ja bsucados + novos valores.

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = corpo; //joga o valor para um elemento html

}

</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" value="0" id="ultimo_id"><!-- campo oculto que armazena o valor do ultimo ID buscado no banco -->

<button type="button" onClick="pegaDados();">CARREGA +</button>

<br>

Dados: <span id="demo"></span>
```

Como pode ver ,passo o valor do ultimo id buscado , entao , na sua pagina que montará o retorno json (pegaPortifolio.php) , voce faz um _get['id'] e usa ele no where ( select * from portifolio where id > $id limit 18) . Assim , ele pega os dados em seguenquecia  , limitando-se a 18 resultados.

Agora , você tem que organizar o resultado do json para poder exibir na sua tela. Recomendo tbm , verificar quantos registros você possui na sua tabela de  "portifolio" , para quando nao ter mas registros para buscar , o botão CARREGA+ seja desabilitado.

Com o javascript não posso ajudar muito pois nao tenho tanto conhecimento sobre o mesmo , mas testei em minha maquina e o mesmo rodou normal .

Comment: Henrique estou usando o plugim isotope jquery para criar uma galeria que puxe do banco de dados, então ela vai ser dinamicamente, quando clickar ele vai aparecer +18 blocos puxados do BD

Comment: para atribuir ao meu código preciso mudar algo?

Comment: no caso aonde está o url: "http://main.xfiddle.com/code_27238237.php?id="+id, eu faço o _get['id'] ??????

Comment: essa function eu faço dentro do pegaPortifolio.php ???

Comment: Boa tarde  , isso. Na pagina pegaPortifolio.php vc faz o $id = $_GET['id'] . Ja na pagina portifolio.php , vc coloca a funcao javascript que manda a requisição para a pagina pegaPortifolio.php

Comment: eu to com problema para entender :/. como vou fazer

Comment: vc poderia fazer o pegaPortifolio.php e portifolio.php de como ficaria no meu codigo?
No meu BD - é banco apixel_galeria TABELA: portfolio

Comment: Boa tarde @kaiquemix , editei o codigo  , deixei bem comentado ele. Faça os teste , as adaptações,  que acredito que vai solucionar seu problema.

Comment: no inspecionar elemento ta aparecendo isso:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost/pixelsbd/json.php?id=0 404 (Not Found)

quando clico no botão careggar mais não acontece nada

Comment: Veja o nome do arquivo e o caminho dele.Isso ai é de arquivo nao encontrado

Comment: sim era o portfolio e nao portifolio heehe
bom agora ta aparecendo só isso:
GET http://localhost/pixelsbd/json.php?id=0 404 (Not Found)

Comment: ta dando erro nessa url... oq eu boto nela?

Comment: Como você nomeou o arquivo que pega os dados do banco  ? No exemplo , eu o chamei de 'json.php' e o deixei no  mesmo diretorio do arquivo que o chama. Verifique o nome do arquivo na sua pagina portifolio.php nessa parte : "url:seu_arquivo.php"

Comment: o portfolio é o index.php
e esse pegarportfolio coloquei dentro de uma pasta ajax/pegarportfolio.php

Comment: coloquei assim,       url: "ajax/pegaPortifolio.php?id="+id,
agora não esta acontecendo nada e não mostra nada no console

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32395/discussion-between-henrique-felix-and-kaiquemix).